# Springframework application context resource resolver

Tags: spring, amazon-s3

Does anyone know how to manipulate a spring application context to use a specified resource resolver. I have written an s3 resource to pull content from a security context from amazon s3, and a resource resolver to create these "resources" from  s3://... type urls, and the local application context uses the right security credentials on load from the configured amazons3client. I've written an s3 ResourceLoader that preconfigure the AmazonS3 client for a newly constructed s3 resource.

It would be nice to be able to specify these resources in the context configuration as simply "s3://..." and rely on this resource resolver to create the right resource type, however, so far this requires overriding the spring ApplicationContext's getResource method inherited from DefaultResourceLoader to use my own resourceResolver implementation.

Another tack is to configure a variable resolver for resources matching the "s3://..." scheme to resolve resource types with that resource resolver.

I am hoping their is a spring guru out their that knows a better way to manipulate the infrastructure of the spring application context (ClasspathXMLAC for arguments sake) to make my S3 security needs very easy to deal with.

Other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Use an implementation of Spring's GenericApplicationContext, which provides you with a #setResourceLoader method.

You mentioned ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, which is not a GenericApplicationContext, meaning that you're forced to take the uglier overriding route.

GenericXmlApplicationContext is a generally preferred alternative to CPXAC, and as the name suggests, is a GenericApplicationContext.

So you should be able to do the following:

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
ctx.setResourceLoader(new S3ResourceLoader());
ctx.load("s3:///some.bucket.name/path/to/my/spring.xml");
ctx.refresh();
...
```

Obviously, the S3ResourceLoader will need to be parameterized with keys, etc.  Note that the S3ResourceLoader should probably extend DefaultResourceLoader in order to pick up all the other functionality available there, e.g. processing "classpath:" and other resource prefixes.

Order of invocation in the above example matters, i.e. the resource loader needs to be provided before #load is called with an s3: resource prefix for obvious reasons.

Comment: I was hoping that this functionality would be picked up due to beans in the context. What I am currently working out is setting up the AmazonS3Client bean followed by a dependent ApplicationContextAware S3Loader bean which extends DefaultResourceLoader, and then having the setApplicationContext do a "If application instance of GenericApplication context, then set the resourceLoader to the s3Loader. However, now my resource loader has to support s3 and MongoDBs GridFS, so I need a new name :P.

Comment: Consider creating a CompositeResourceLoader that delegates to N ResourceLoader instances.  You can then have discrete S3-, Mongo-, and GridFS-based ResourceLoaders, aggregate them all under a single CompositeResourceLoader, and hand that off to the GenericApplicationContext#setResourceLoader method.